# How to exclude anonymous questions/users in search query

Tags: support, search, filtering

Is there a way to exclude anonymous users/questions in a search query? An anonymous user/question to me means that the question is asked by a "userXXXXXXXX"?

Comment: That's not anonymous. A username like userXXXXXX is just a user that didn't want to choose a user name, but it's not anonymous.

Comment: Nope. And there are plenty of userxxxx users with valuable contributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like said in comments, **user with `userXXXXXXX` name aren't anonymous**. These profiles are from people who didn't choose a username and so, to identify them, the website attributes to them a username with a random ID.
If they were anonymous, you shouldn't be able to look at their profile page and see every questions/answers they have posted.

Since they are users like you and me, there's no special filters to exclude their questions.

Comment: There are afaik no anonymous users (unless you mean those who have their accounts deleted). There are unregistered users, but those do have a profile page.

Answer (score 1):

I would take that username of userxxxxxx as the x being replaced by the integer something like [user3316081](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3316081/user3316081). That is the username of the user, who is not anonymous. He just did not take pain to edit his profile to share his name and username on the profile. You can see my profile, my name is **Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan** and the username I have is **afzaal-ahmad-zeeshan**.

The Anonymous users are named Anonymous, and are not these accounts that have 7 integers at the end of their **user** name.